# SocketIO off / dereference one of listeners on same socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Suppose I have a single socket sending a message like `renderUpdate` which may pertain to lots of different instances of a class called `RenderClient`, all listening for an update on the same socket simultaneously.

When `renderUpdate` fires from the socket, each instance of `RenderClient` reads the update and decides if it pertains to that particular rendering, and if so, returns a result and destroys its listener.

It's urgent that the listener be destroyed so that `RenderClient` can be garbage collected and we don't have extra listeners hanging around. However, every `RenderClient` has to listen to the same event -- `renderUpdate` -- and there seems to be no namespacing `renderUpdate.clientID` in the SocketIO API.

Is there a well-trodden design pattern for many instances listening on the same Node SocketIO socket to dereference their listeners individually without calling `off()` on the whole socket?

For example...

```
class RenderView {
...
    private async _render(opts:TD.RenderOptions):Promise {
        this.renderConn.socket.on('renderUpdate',(update:TD.RenderResponse)=>this._onUpdate(update));
    }
    private _onUpdate(update:TD.RenderResponse):void {
        if (update.renderingID==this.renderingID)
           this._lastUpdate = update;
           //do some stuff if the render update from the socket pertains to this RenderView.
    }
    public async destroy():Promise {
        this.renderConn.socket.off('renderUpdate'); // HERE!
    }
```

@ "HERE!" I don't want to stop ALL listeners for the socket on 'renderUpdate', just the one for THIS instance of RenderView.

Comment: Well, there's is connection reuse, but it seems like your misusing socket.io, and you should implement observer / an event bus in your client yourself. Really hard to provide an answer without more fully fleshed out code example. Please provide a simplified (i.e. strip out the noise and application detail, and even the typing) working example.

Comment: In the simplest form, the server is running a bunch of renderings for the client. The client has one socket open to the server. The server server emits `("renderUpdate",{id:id})` to the client whenever ANY of that client's renderings updates. On the client side, there are a lot of listeners for the same message handle (renderUpdate) on the same socket. In e.g. JQuery you can namespace listeners by saying `on('eventname.namespace')` and then `off('.namespace')` would only turn off the one for that particular instance w/o turning off ALL listeners for the `eventname`. Does this explain better?

Comment: Another way to say it is I have many objects in the client listening for the same 'eventName' on the socket, but when I say `socket.off('eventName')` I only want to detach that one object's listener ...not all listeners for the same event on the socket.

Comment: I guess if I passed the same instance of function call to the second param of `off()` then it should only dereference the specific event. But I'm using an anonymous function so I'm not storing the instance to `off` it explicitly.